# How to fix Firefox so that it load certain sites like Netflix?

Tags: networking, firefox, ipv6, netflix

So, I've been having this issue with the *Netflix* site on Firefox on **Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.3** 64-bit. While any other site works flawlessly, the Netflix site didn't load with a weird "Server not found" error, despite other browsers loading the site with no issues, and other sites on Firefox loading perfectly.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I tried several of the possible options in the [official Firefox site](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/server-not-found-connection-problem), but this was the one that got it working:

> 1. In the address bar, type `about:config` and press Enter.
> 2. The `about:config` "This might void your warranty!" warning page may appear.
>
>    Click I accept the risk! to continue to the
>      about:config page.
> 3. In the Search field, enter **network.dns.disableIPv6**
>          In the list of preferences, double-click network.dns.disableIPv6 to change its value from *false* to *true*.

Comment: Obviously this is not actually a solution, but a temporary workaround for whatever the real problem is.

Comment: I totally agree with you @MichaelHampton. The actual reason that this error is beyond my understanding of what might be the cause for it. I hope that someone else finds a better or definite solution, because disabling ipv6 is not a good thing to do in the long run.

Comment: @luisgonzalez if your internet connection don't have IPv6 (or don't have it properly configured) you don't loose anything by disabling IPv6.

Comment: @luisgonzalez, if you are running Firefox Quantum, should see [this Mozilla Article](https://support.mozilla.org/pt-BR/questions/1178557)